# The batch just close when i want to write into a vbs script

Tags: batch-file

I don't know why this code don't make a vbs file... The batch window just close when i call it.

I searched on google how to make it work, but i didn't found something to help me.

```
(echo Dim oPlayer
echo Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
echo oPlayer.URL = sound.mp3
echo oPlayer.controls.play 
echo While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped 
echo WScript.Sleep 100 
echo oPlayer.close ) > testname.vbs
pause
```

How to make it work?

Comment: You need to escape problem characters, e.g. `....OCX"^)` and `State ^<^> 1`.

Comment: i figured it out... thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm aware, due to your answer, that you'd figured out that some characters required escaping, but you created an answer which did not indicate which characters needed that treatment, only some. The comment I made showed that the closing parenthesis needed escaping too, your answer does not therefore help other users moving forward and is therefore inadequate.

Comment: i said "like here: ..." not "i had to add ^ here:...". I understand what you are sayin', my answer was not complete.

Comment: If you make it complete, you could subsequently mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I had to add some ^ at comands. I changed this 2 commands:

```
echo Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
echo While oPlayer.playState <> 1
```

in

```
echo Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo While oPlayer.playState ^<^> 1
```